# How does R assign a resolution to raster objects?

Tags: r, r-raster

Suppose one runs the following R code

```
install.packages("raster")
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=18, nrow=18)
res(r)
```

The output of the `res` function is

```
[1] 20 10
```

How are these values defined? How does the `raster` function calculate them? In what units are they expressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from the [vignette](https://rspatial.org/raster/pkg/3-objects.html)

> The default settings will create a global raster data structure with a longitude/latitude coordinate reference system and 1 by 1 degree cells.

```r
r
# class       : RasterLayer 
# dimensions  : 18, 18, 324  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution  : 20, 10  (x, y)
# extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84
```

`r` **x** extent goes to from -180 to +180 degrees by default (a total of 360 degrees), and 360 degrees / 18 points = a **x** resolution of 20 degrees.

`r` **y** extent goes form -90 to +90 degrees by default, and 180 degrees / 18 points results in a **y** resolution of 10 degrees.

Comment: Should check out those vignettes more often. Thank you very much for your answer Guillaume.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Guillaume Devailly, the horizontal resolution is the horizontal extent divided by the number of columns. The vertical resolution is the vertical extent divided by the number of rows. The units are the units of your coordinate reference system. The default is degrees (for longitude/latitude). To add more to Guillaume's answer:

Create a raster with 10 rows and columns that goes from 0 to 10. The resolution is 1.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10, xmn=0, xmx=10, ymn=0, ymx=10)
r
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent     : 0, 10, 0, 10  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

Change the resolution to 0.5; the number of rows and columns double

```
res(r) <- 0.5
r
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 20, 20, 400  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
#extent     : 0, 10, 0, 10  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

You can change the resolution indirectly by adjusting the extent

```
extent(r) <- c(0,5,0,5)
r
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 20, 20, 400  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
#extent     : 0, 5, 0, 5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

The x and y resolution can be set to a different value

```
res(r) <- c(1, 0.5)
```

When you change the resolution directly, via `res` any cell values associated with the Raster* object are lost; because the number of rows or columns has to change. If you change it indirectly, by changing the extent, the values stay.

Comment: Thanks, that was written a bit too hastily ---- I edited the text

Comment: thanks very much. And an even greater thank you for the package itself!